# Unresolved symbols and types while using HashDRBG from libgcrypt in C

Tags: c, random, libgcrypt

I have a problem using the HashDRBG from libgcrypt. My goal is to get some random data from a seed:

outbuf <--- DRBG_HASHSHA512(seed)

The only option I've seen so far is using libgrypt:
 (https://fossies.org/linux/libgcrypt/random/random-drbg.c)

Regarding the instructions, I have to use something like:

```
gcry_control(GCRYCTL_DRBG_REINIT, DRBG_NOPR_CTRAES128, NULL);
```

to initialize it depending on the DRBG type.
But I always get the error: 
"Symbol 'DRBG_NOPR_CTRAES128' could not be resolved". The same with other DRBG types.

As well as "Type 'drbg_string_t' could not be resolved", when I want to use the *additional information string*.
I have *gcrypt.h* included and the libraries linked with `libgcrypt-config --cflags --libs`.

The generation of the random stream should then be done by:

```
gcry_randomize(outbuf, OUTLEN, GCRY_STRONG_RANDOM);
```

This function call worked at least for the default parameters.

Has anybody an idea on how to enable these missing functionalities? Thank you.